# Python log filenames from a directory to a text file

Tags: python

I need help to make a python script that copies the names of the files in a certain directory and pastes them in a text file. The conditions are that If I delete a file from the directory the text file will still have the file name. If I add a new file and ran the python script then it adds it to the list.

what the directory looks like:

[image]

what the text file look  like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add what you have tried by far and make sure to check our help pages on [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hints to help you to start your script and then improve this question or ask a new (better) one: you will need `os.listdir` and a `set` could help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using `if x not in listfile` which checks if the string I am looking for is not in the text file.

```
    import os
items = os.listdir(".")

newlist = []
for names in items:
    newlist.append(names)

filename = open("filenames.txt")
listname = filename.readlines()
listname = [x.strip("\n") for x in listname]
filename.close()

store = open("filenames.txt","a")
for x in newlist:
    if x not in listname:
        store.write(x + "\n")
```